# Is there another way of testing if a big.Int is 0?

Tags: performance, go, comparison, bigint

I'm working with `big.Int`s and need to test for 0. Right now, I'm using `zero = big.NewInt(0)`and `Cmp(zero)==0` which works fine, but I was wondering if there's a quicker way specifically for 0 (I need this program to be very fast)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`big.Int`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int) exposes [`Int.Bits()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.Bits) to access the raw bytes of the representation, which is a slice and it shares the same underlying array: the returned slice is not copied. So it's fast. It's exposed to *"support implementation of missing low-level Int functionality"*.

Perfect, exactly what we want.

### 0. Testing for `0`

Documentation of `big.Int` also states that *"the zero value for an Int represents the value 0"*. So in the zero value (which represents `0`) the slice will be empty (zero value for slices is `nil` and the length of a `nil` slice is `0`). We can simply check that:

```
if len(i1.Bits()) == 0 {
}
```

Also note that there is an [`Int.BitLen()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.BitLen) function returning this, which also states that *"the bit length of 0 is 0"*. So we may also use this:

```
if i1.BitLen() == 0 {
}
```

Let's benchmark these solutions:

```
func BenchmarkCompare(b *testing.B) {
    zero := big.NewInt(0)
    i1 := big.NewInt(1)
    i2 := big.NewInt(0)
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        if i1.Cmp(zero) == 0 {
        }
        if i2.Cmp(zero) == 0 {
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkBits(b *testing.B) {
    i1 := big.NewInt(1)
    i2 := big.NewInt(0)
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        if len(i1.Bits()) == 0 {
        }
        if len(i2.Bits()) == 0 {
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkBitLen(b *testing.B) {
    i1 := big.NewInt(1)
    i2 := big.NewInt(0)
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        if i1.BitLen() == 0 {
        }
        if i2.BitLen() == 0 {
        }
    }
}
```

Benchmark results:

```
BenchmarkCompare-8      76975251            13.3 ns/op
BenchmarkBits-8         1000000000           0.656 ns/op
BenchmarkBitLen-8       1000000000           1.11 ns/op
```

Getting the bits and comparing the slice length to `0` is **20 times faster** than comparing it to another `big.Int` representing `0`, using `Int.BitLen()` is also **10 times faster**.

### 1. Testing for `1`

Something similar could be made to test if a `big.Int` value equals to `1`, but probably not as fast as testing for zero: `0` is the most special value. Its internal representation is a `nil` slice, any other value requires a non-`nil` slice. Also: `0` has another special property: its absolute value is itself.

This absolute value property is important, because `Int.Bits()` returns the absolute value. So in case of a non-zero value checking just the bits slice is insufficient, as it carries no sign information.

So testing for `1` can be implemented by checking if the bits content represents `1`, and the sign is positive:

```
func isOne(i *big.Int) bool {
    bits := i.Bits()
    return len(bits) == 1 && bits[0] == 1 && i.Sign() > 0
}
```

Let's benchmark this along with comparing the number to `one := big.NewInt(1)`:

```
func BenchmarkCompareOne(b *testing.B) {
    one := big.NewInt(1)
    i1 := big.NewInt(0)
    i2 := big.NewInt(1)
    i3 := big.NewInt(2)
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        if i1.Cmp(one) == 0 {
        }
        if i2.Cmp(one) == 0 {
        }
        if i3.Cmp(one) == 0 {
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkBitsOne(b *testing.B) {
    i1 := big.NewInt(0)
    i2 := big.NewInt(1)
    i3 := big.NewInt(2)
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        if isOne(i1) {
        }
        if isOne(i2) {
        }
        if isOne(i3) {
        }
    }
}
```

And the benchmark results:

```
BenchmarkCompareOne-8       58631458            18.9 ns/op
BenchmarkBitsOne-8          715606629            1.76 ns/op
```

Not bad! Our way of testing for 1 is again **10 times faster**.

Comment: Thanks! Can a similar method be used to check if x is 1?

Comment: @lolad Probably a solution more efficient than `Int.Cmp()` could be created, but not as fast as the above zero check: `0` is the most special value.

Comment: @lolad ...and there you have it. See edited answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! :)