# Why big.NewInt(0).Bytes() returns [] instead of [0] in Go?

Tags: go

I find it weird that running `big.NewInt(0).Bytes()` returns `[]` instead of `[0]`. Is it really supposed to work that way?

https://play.golang.org/p/EEaS8sCvhFb

Comment: Not sure why exactly go does it, but it makes sense. From your playground link, you are not suprised that `Bytes()` does not return two bytes for 255. This number doesn't need to have any bits set in the second byte, so why return it as an insignificant 0, right? Similarly here, number 0 does not need to have any bits set even in the first byte.

Comment: "Is it really supposed to work that way?" is a question for the package author, but seeing as it has worked that way for a decade, I wouldn't think it's incorrect behavior; particularly as calling `SetBytes([]byte{})` yields `0`, making the behavior consistent.

Comment: {} is a common mathematical representation for 0 so this looks very natural from a set theoretic perspective.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Bytes() doesnt return two bytes because it returns absolute value of int.

Comment: @Toni: this is a _non sequitur_. Value 255 can be represented by `00 FF` (I'm using big endian here), just as well as by `FF`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I propably misunderstood something. Sorry about that. I expect `big.NewInt(255).Bytes()` to be `FF` and not `00 FF` just like I expect `big.NewInt(-255).Bytes()` to be `FF` and not `FF 01`.

Comment: @Toni: that is my point exactly. zero bytes in insignificant positions are not needed. And in case of `big.NewInt(0)` all bytes are insignificant zeroes.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I completely understand that zero bytes in insignificant positions are not needed. Im not sure my brains can agree that all bytes in case of `big.NewInt(0).Bytes()` are insignificant but I can live with that :) And there is always `big.NewInt(0).FillBytes(...)` too. Thanks @SergioTulentsev and all the others!

Answer (score 5):

[`big.Int`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int) is a struct. It's idiomatic to make the [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) useful whenever possible. `big.Int` is no exception: The zero value for an `Int` represents the value `0`.

It's an implementation detail, but the data of the `Int` is stored in a slice. The zero value for slices is `nil`, that is: no elements.

So this is very convenient, and very efficient. `0` is probably the most frequent value, and there may be cases where an initial `big.Int` won't get changed, and so no slice for the internal representation will be allocated.

See related: [Is there another way of testing if a big.Int is 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64257065/is-there-another-way-of-testing-if-a-big-int-is-0/64257532#64257532)

Comment: Its efficient if that 0 byte doesent matter. On the other hand if you need that 0 byte to be there then its inefficient to always check and handle that 0 value separately. But I quess its a tradeoff of that "efficiency".

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.Bytes):

> Bytes returns the absolute value of x as a big-endian byte slice.

The package API doesn't define how many bytes long the slice will be. In this case, it's using the smallest number of bytes needed to convey the whole number.

The more likely reason why this happens is an implementation detail: The `big.Int` maintains the bytes of the number in a slice. `nil` slices in Go (the zero value of a slice) have length 0. When a `big.Int` value is initially created, we'd expect it to also have a value of `0`. Therefore, it simplifies the implementation if an empty slice internally corresponds to a numerical value of `0`, without needing to perform extra checks or padding.