# Negative big.Int turns positive after using Int64() conversion due integer overflow

Tags: go, math, comparison, bigint

I have a simple if statement which compares two numbers. I couldn't use `big.Int` to compare with zero due to compile error, therefore I tried to convert to an int64 and to a float32. The problem is that after calling `Int64` or `float32(diff.Int64())`, `diff` gets converted into a positive number which is a result of an integer overflow I suspect. I would appreciate if somebody could show me what is the safe way to prepare the `diff` variable for the comparison with zero.

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {
    var amount1 = &big.Int{}
    var amount2 = &big.Int{}
    amount1.SetString("465673065724131968098", 10)
    amount2.SetString("500000000000000000000", 10)

    diff := big.NewInt(0).Sub(amount1, amount2)
    fmt.Println(diff)
    // -34326934275868031902 << this is the correct number which should be compared to 0

    fmt.Println(diff.Int64())
    // 2566553871551071330 << this is what the if statement compares to 0
    if diff.Int64() > 0 {
       fmt.Println(float64(diff.Int64()), "is bigger than 0")
    }

}
```

Comment: You can't fit 69 bits of information in a 64 bit value. Compare the number using the `math/big` package. What did you try, and what was the compilation error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Int.Cmp()`](https://pkg.go.dev/math/big#Int.Cmp) to compare it to another [`big.Int`](https://pkg.go.dev/math/big#Int) value, one representing `0`.

For example:

```
zero := new(big.Int)

switch result := diff.Cmp(zero); result {
case -1:
    fmt.Println(diff, "is less than", zero)
case 0:
    fmt.Println(diff, "is", zero)
case 1:
    fmt.Println(diff, "is greater than", zero)
}
```

This will output:

```
-34326934275868031902 is less than 0
```

When comparing to the special `0`, instead you could also use [`Int.Sign()`](https://pkg.go.dev/math/big#Int.Sign) which returns -1, 0, +1 depending on the result of the comparison to `0`.

```
switch sign := diff.Sign(); sign {
case -1:
    fmt.Println(diff, "is negative")
case 0:
    fmt.Println(diff, "is 0")
case 1:
    fmt.Println(diff, "is positive")
}
```

This will output:

```
-34326934275868031902 is negative
```

Try the examples on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/f8uDBcFmk8H).

See related:

[Is there another way of testing if a big.Int is 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64257065/is-there-another-way-of-testing-if-a-big-int-is-0/64257532#64257532)