# Why is the .Bytes() value of a 0 big.Int an empty slice?

Tags: go, slice, bigint

Why does calling `.Bytes()` on a zero value `big.Int` return a slice of length 0?

```golang
    // uint64
    var x uint64
    xb := make([]byte, 8)
    binary.BigEndian.PutUint64(xb, x)
    // [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
    fmt.Println(xb)

    // uint8
    var y uint8
    yb := []byte{byte(y)}
    // [0]
    fmt.Println(yb)

    // big.Int
    z := big.Int{}
    zb := z.Bytes()
    // []               Why is this an empty slice and not [0]
    fmt.Println(zb)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`big.Int`](https://pkg.go.dev/math/big#Int) stores the absolute value of the number it represents in a slice. `big.Int` documents that *"the zero value for an Int represents the value 0"*. So in the zero value (which represents `0`) the slice will be empty (zero value for slices is `nil` and the length of a `nil` slice is `0`).

The reasoning is simple: in cases where you don't use a `big.Int` value, it won't require allocation for the slice. Zero is the most special and probably the most frequent value, using this simple trick is a "no-brainer" optimization.

See related question: [Is there another way of testing if a big.Int is 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64257065/is-there-another-way-of-testing-if-a-big-int-is-0/64257532#64257532)